# FTP - сервер в домашних условиях

Tags: сеть, подсети, ftp-сервер

*- Когда в руках есть что-то, чем можно управлять, бери и управляй! (автор вопроса).*
А вот когда нет?
Возможно кто-то уже и реализовывал такое через провайдера.

• Схема 1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

• Схема 2 (с использованием обычного hub'ика)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Почему спрашиваю здесь, потому-что провайдер в лице "специалистов" аля девочек-припевочек, ни чего толком ответить не может, телефоны отдела ИТ не дают, на письма не отвечают.
Маршрутизацию, эти девочки, представляют лишь на оборудовании абонента.
Вот нет у меня маршрутизатора и приобретать его не собираюсь.
Или же провайдеры такого не делают?
Но вот те девочки-припевочки, ой, т.е. - "**Специалисты ТЕХНИЧЕСКОЙ(!) поддержки**", заявляют "что всё будет работать". Но я как-то побаиваюсь вызывать такси, возить оборудование туда сюда.
Вот и пытаюсь выяснить, реализовывал кто такое и есть ли, какие-либо, подводные камни от провайдеров?

P.S. минусы от пришедших новых "умников" с ответов "мой мымр"?
Я не сетевик, и как узнал позже? есть реализация пробросом портов на самом ПК.
http://winitpro.ru/index.php/2014/12/23/nastrojka-port-forvardinga-v-windows
Но минусовщики вряд ли и об этом знают!
2. Реализовал всё-таки через маршрутизатор. Сначала дали DIR-100-ку, потом выделили средства уже на DIR-615R.
Удачи вам минусовщики, смотрите не лопните от распирающей вас "умности"!

Comment: Как-то чересчур эмоционально

Comment: Провайдер дает "белый" IP?

Comment: @Anatol возможно, так как уже заколебала бестолковая стена "специалистов" у провайдера. - "На электронную почту можете и написать, но всё равно вам не ответят." - официальный ответ "специалиста тех.поддержки". Интересно, для чего тогда им она?

Comment: @Zufir да, он будет приобретаться.
Почему я всё и уточняю, чтобы потом не требовать возврата денег за все действия. Тем-более, что в низ по тарифу отката нет.

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от конкретных реализаций сетей вашего провайдера. 
Если вы хотите сделать ваш сервер доступным из вне, то как минимум вам нужен будет постоянный адрес, по которому был бы доступен сервер.
Как правило, большинство провайдеров такой адрес выделяют за отдельную плату, либо, как альтернатива, можно использовать какой-либо сервис, например, [NoIP](http://www.noip.com/). Не забываем так же про DNS.

Вторая сложность - это порты. Например, у некоторых провайдеров может быть закрыт 21 порт на вход. Типа, забота о безопасности. Это тоже нужно выяснить, например, при помощи [такого сервиса](https://2ip.ru/check-port/), или любого альтернативного.

После того, как входящие пакеты по 21-му порту попали в вашу сеть, нужно перенаправить их на ваш сервер. Значит нужно будет делать проброс портов, либо маршрутизировать это дело иным образом.

У вас в вопросе мало информации, как технической, например, что может или не может провайдер дать (тот же IP и открытый порт), как и через что осуществляется сейчас подключение к сети, какие ОС используете или планируете использовать для сервера, как именно сервер FTP хотели бы использовать.

Потому дать непосредственно пошаговый алгоритм настройки затруднительно.

Но вообще, раз уж хотите использовать опыт других, то можно почитать [статьи](http://sonikelf.ru/sozdaem-svoj-sobstvennyj-ftp-server-na-baze-filezilla-server/) по соответствующей тематике, где вполне [описано все по шагам](http://www.dimonius.ru/?ftphowto) для общих случаев.

Ну и да, если у вас будет не получаться что-то конкретное, то вновь можно будет задать вопрос тут.

P.S. Если провайдер вас не устраивает, то почему бы его не сменить, при условии. что есть альтернативы?

Comment: ip - приобретается абонентом. Порты открыта с утверждения этих же самых "специалистов".
Сам сервер настроен и прошёл тестирование (при управляемом маршрутизаторе, на нём был реализован проброс портов до ПК внутри сети).
Но тут ситуация в том, то приходит уже просто кончик с интернетом и  никакого другого оборудования нет. Приобретать пока ещё не решил.
Скорее всего придётся всё сделать до тупости приметивно - заказать у провайдеоа второй провод на который и будет идти белый ip. И порты пробрасывать ни где не придётся.

Comment: С отдельным хвостом - это самый простой вариант, конечно, отдельный провод для FTP, и с точки зрения безопасности лучше. Дороже, видимо, но это уже другой аспект совсем.